# Search the latest text only when replying

Tags: vba, email, search, outlook

I have written an Outlook VBA script to prompt a message box with an email summary that reminds users to check before the email is sent.

One of the features is to check whether the attachment is missing if the email contains "attach" or "enclose" strings.

When replying to an email which contains these words, the prompt as a result of the search including the appended part becomes meaningless. I want to know how to exclude searching the appended part. The following is part of my script:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim mailContent As String
   mailContent = LCase(Item.Body)
   If (Item.Attachments.Count = 0) Then
       If InStr(1, mailContent, "attach") <> 0 Or InStr(1, mailContent, "enclose") <> 0 Then
           If MsgBox("With the word 'attach' or 'enclose', attachment should be found in this email. Proceed?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Missing Attachment") = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no property in a MailItem object that will allow you to differentiate between the new text and the reply text.  One option is to get a handle to the source email when the user replies to it, and compare the message body between the new and the old.

Why do you need to trap attachment related keywords though? That feature is already built into Outlook 2013+.

Comment: Thank you. It is really sad.I know Outlook 2013 or newer provides this function, but it works not very well and not all my colleagues' computers have 2013+ installed.